# Ubuntu 20.04 does not allow me to use the same device for sound input and output

Tags: sound, 20.04, input-devices, output

I have been having this problem since the clean installation I made of ubuntu 20.04 lts (before I used 18.04) with the exact same hardware and it worked very well.

Whenever I need to make a video call I have this problem, because I would like to use the headset as a sound input and output at the same time, but the system does not allow me to make this selection in any way.

[image: what happens when I try to select]

What could be happening?

The problem happens both with the Sony wireless headset (Pulse elite) and with a simple one connected to the 2.5 mm connection.
I have a dual boot with windows 10 on the same laptop and everything works fine, than I suppose, there is not a hardware problem.